# How to automate the "check for update automatically?" in java control panel?

Tags: java, security, deployment, applet, controlpanel

I need to uncheck the "**check for updates automatically**" which is in the **java control panel**(Update tab).

I **need to automate** the above process. Am using windows XP(32 bit), and java version **1.7.0_25**. I tried via "**deployment.properties**" file, but no use.

Could you please advise me the possibilities in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deal with Windows XP shell programming, via JNI.
I would think twice before start implement. - I do not recommend.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to turn it off by modifying Windows registry. Find `JavaUpdate` node in Windows registry (using regedit). There should be `UpdateSchedule` key somewhere under it. Modify it to 0 to turn off automatic updates.

I am on Windows 7 64-bit with Java 7 and the registry key is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy\JavaFX\UpdateSchedule`. I think it could be different for different Windows and Java versions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any possibility other than registry update? Because in some system not having the admin rights.

Comment: I am afraid that there is no way to change that setting without admin rights. You need admin rights even if you want to change it in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy\JavaFX\UpdateSchedule
> ```

By trial and error I found the following reg settings:

- **EnableAutoUpdateCheck=0 (SZ)**
- **EnableJavaUpdate=1 (Dword)**

  - I believe these turn the auto updates on and off (currently set to "on")
- **Frequency=127 (Dword)**

  - 127=Daily
  - 1=Weekly on Sunday
  - 2,4,6,16,32,64=weekly on Mon...Sat
  - 16842752=monthly on Sunday
- **NotifyDownload=0 (Dword)**
- **NotifyInstall=1 (Dword)**

  - Together, these two set it to "Notify Me: Before Installing".
  - "Notify Me: Before Downloading" is 1,0 instead of 0,1
- **UpdateSchedule=15 (Dword)**

  - 15=3pm. Obvious why.

Win7 64bit - Java 7u45 32bit (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
With this info you can probably change these settings in XP easily.